# Is method reference calling constructor of ArrayNode class under the hood?

Tags: java

I have an example of program, which uses method reference operator (double colon):

```
public class VersionNumberComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    @Override
    public int compare(String version1, String version2) {
        Integer[] array1 = Arrays.stream(version1.split("\\."))
                .map(Integer::parseInt)
                .toArray(Integer[]::new);
        Integer[] array2 = Arrays.stream(version2.split("\\."))
                .map(Integer::parseInt)
                .toArray(Integer[]::new);
        int length1 = array1.length;
        int length2 = array2.length;
        int idx = 0;
        while (idx < length1 || idx < length2) {
            if (idx < length1 && idx < length2) {
                if (array1[idx] < array2[idx]) {
                    return -1;
                } else if (array1[idx] > array2[idx]) {
                    return 1;
                }
            } else if (idx < length1) {
                if (array1[idx] != 0) {
                    return 1;
                }
            } else {
                if (array2[idx] != 0) {
                    return -1;
                }
            }
            idx++;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Before comparing the version numbers of application, I need to split numbers and compare each from the left side to the right:

```
Integer[] array1 = Arrays.stream(version1.split("\\."))
                    .map(Integer::parseInt)
                    .toArray(Integer[]::new);
Integer[] array2 = Arrays.stream(version2.split("\\."))
                    .map(Integer::parseInt)
                    .toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

Method reference has four types. And one of it is: reference to a constructor `ClassName::new`.
So if I'm debugging and making a step into `.toArray(Integer[]::new);`, I'm getting:

```
@Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public final <A> A[] toArray(IntFunction<A[]> generator) {
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        IntFunction rawGenerator = (IntFunction) generator;
        return (A[]) Nodes.flatten(evaluateToArrayNode(rawGenerator), rawGenerator)
                              .asArray(rawGenerator);
    }
```

and then:

```
    /** Node class for a reference array */
    private static class ArrayNode<T> implements Node<T> {
        final T[] array;
        int curSize;

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        ArrayNode(long size, IntFunction<T[]> generator) {
            if (size >= MAX_ARRAY_SIZE)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(BAD_SIZE);
            this.array = generator.apply((int) size);
            this.curSize = 0;
        }
...
```

Do I understand correctly in this particular case method reference is calling constructor of ArrayNode class under the hood as it requires operator `::`?

Comment: No. Integer[]::new is a reference to the constructor of Integer[]. When it's invoked, it thus constructs a new Integer[], i.e. a new array of Integers.

Comment: The method `evaluateArrayNode` eventually calls the `ArrayNode` constructor, indirectly through about 6 other intermediate method calls. Thus, there is no relation to the constructor referenced through the `::` syntax. In fact, in the last code block that is presented, the parameter `generator` references `Integer[]::new`. You can check this by assigning it to a local variable and comparing the the object ids through eclipses Variables View or [`System.identityHashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode-java.lang.Object-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method evaluateArrayNode eventually calls the ArrayNode constructor, indirectly through a series of intermediate method calls.

From my Debug view:

```
// this.array = generator.apply((int) size);
Nodes$FixedNodeBuilder<T>(Nodes$ArrayNode<T>).<init>(long, IntFunction<T[]>) line: 646
Nodes$FixedNodeBuilder<T>.<init>(long, IntFunction<T[]>) line: 1199 
Nodes.builder(long, IntFunction<T[]>) line: 167
ReferencePipeline$3(ReferencePipeline<P_IN,P_OUT>).makeNodeBuilder(long, IntFunction<P_OUT[]>) line: 131
ReferencePipeline$3(AbstractPipeline<E_IN,E_OUT,S>).evaluate(Spliterator<P_IN>, boolean, IntFunction<E_OUT[]>) line: 543
ReferencePipeline$3(AbstractPipeline<E_IN,E_OUT,S>).evaluateToArrayNode(IntFunction<E_OUT[]>) line: 260
ReferencePipeline$3(ReferencePipeline<P_IN,P_OUT>).toArray(IntFunction<A[]>) line: 438
// Arrays.stream(new int[] { }).toArray(Integer[]::new);
Test.main(String[]) line: 15
```

Thus, there is no relation to the constructor referenced through the `::` syntax.

In fact, in the last code block that is presented, the parameter `generator` references `Integer[]::new`. You can check this by implementing the generator function yourself, for example:

```
class Generator implements IntFunction<Integer[]> {
    @Override
    public Integer[] apply(int value) {
        System.out.println(new Exception().getStackTrace()[2]);
        return new Integer[value];
    }
}
```

and

```
Arrays.stream(new int[] { }).toArray(new Generator());
```

This will print:

```
java.util.stream.Nodes$ArrayNode.<init>(Nodes.java:646)
```

Which is this exact line:

```
this.array = generator.apply((int) size);
```